# How to click a LinkButton with JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, onclick

I had before this code that worked very well, but now, it does not work anymore in Chrome and IE10. I don't know why

Javascript

```
    function EnterEvent(e, ctrl) {
        var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (keycode == 13) {
            $('[id$=btnSave]').click();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" runat="server" onkeyup="EnterEvent(event, this)" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Server side

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Operations
    }
```

I ve already replaced this `$('[id$=btnAddItem]').click();` with `$('#btnAddItem').click();` but nothing at all. The server side is never triggered.

I had my controls in a ajaxpanel but like this it worked before. I tested with F12 developer tools. I arrived to the click part but nothing

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: if you have it inside an update panel, you need to re-initialize it after update panels updates... do you do that ?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with an id that ends with btnAddItem? Your selector matches "an element whose 'id' attribute value ends exactly with the string 'btnAddItem'"

Comment: @Aristos How do I re-initialize?

Comment: @Pavlo , that's the only element $('[id$=btnSave]') when I debug this with F12 I can see just one element

Comment: @Pavlo Server side of the click is not working.

Comment: @Pavlo Oh, excuse me, I forgot to include the control that calls the click with the enter. It's a textbox just aside of the linkbutton. See my edit question

Comment: @MaximusDecimus are you able to alert anything inside `if (keycode == 13) { alert('a')}` ?

Comment: @Pavlo. Yes I already did and it works the alert

Comment: @MaximusDecimus Can you add some css class to your link button, for example `myClass` and change this `$('[id$=btnSave]').click();` to `$('.myClass').click();`

Comment: @MaximusDecimus See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257973/how-do-you-get-client-side-script-to-execute-on-an-asp-net-postback-from-an-up/3258167#3258167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. The only thing that I needed to do was to replace this line from my code

```
$('[id$=btnSave]').click();
```

for this:

```
__doPostBack(linkCtrl, '');
```

The signature of the function ended like this.

```
function EnterEvent(e, ctrl, linkCtrl) {
```

And finally I assigned this event in the OnLoad and postback == false

```
txtAdd.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "EnterEvent(event, this, '" + this.btnSave.UniqueID + "')"
```